# How to import a sibling module in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

In python3, this:

```
from xxx import *
```

Gives me an error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'xxx'
```

Which I was not getting with python2.7. Leaving aside style (`import *` is not nice), how can I make this import statement python3 compatible, using minimally invasive method? Since this is coming from a third-party difficult to collaborate with, I do not want to change too much; specifically, I would like to avoid having to change the use of the names imported from `xxx`.

### EDIT

Directory structure is:

```
├── xxx.py
├── yyy.py
└── __init__.py
```

Module `yyy.py` has the `from xxx import *` statement.

Comment: The import statement is compatible with python 3 so there must be more to your question

Comment: Directory structure pls

Comment: @GermanRosales: added!

Answer (score 0):

You should use relative import by using `.` like this:

```
from .xxx import *
```

This statement import everything from the xxx module placed right next to the current module

Comment: xxx is a sibling of yyy, and I am doing `from xxx import *` in `yyy.py`

Comment: so you placed it right next to the yyy? if so use ``from .xxx import *``